# Html not displaying correctly in email

Tags: html, css, html-email

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="social-links">
        <img src="http://www.collegify.com/emailer/roads/delhi/images/Promotional_03.jpg" alt="">
        www.twitter.com/roadsprep
        <br />
        <img src="http://www.collegify.com/emailer/roads/delhi/images/Promotional_09.jpg" alt="">
        www.facebook.com/roadsprep
    </div>
    <div id="website-link">www.roadsprep.com</div>
    <div id="now-at-gurgaon">
        NOW AT
        <BR />
        GURGAON
    </div>
    <div id="gray-box">
        We specialize in
        <br />
        SAT, GRE, GMAT, ACT
        <br />
        IELTS and TOEFL coaching!
    </div>
    <div id="pointers">
        <ul>
            <li>Over 6 years of Test Prep Experience!</li>
            <li>Over 300 students with 2100 + scores</li>
            <li>On average, an improvement of 400 point improvement in scores</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-info">
        <strong>Roads Academy Private Limited</strong>
        <br />
        Office No. 4001, Basement, DLF Phase IV, Near, Galleria Market, Gurgaon - 122 009, Haryana
        <br />
        <strong>Phone:</strong>
        +91 85100 66662
        <strong>Email:</strong>
        support@roadsprep.com
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#container {
    background-image: url(http://www.collegify.com/emailer/roads/delhi/images/Promotional-Flyer-for-Delhi-Front-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 600px;
    height: 910px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 31px;
}
#social-links {
    margin: 0 0 0 32px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 57px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#website-link {
    margin: 0 21px 0 0;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#now-at-gurgaon {
    margin: 230px 0 0 128px;
    color: #454b4f;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 181px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#gray-box {
    background-color: #454a4e;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    border-top: solid 1px #1b1d21;
    margin-top: 315px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #fbc911;
}
#pointers {
    width: 280px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #454a4e;
}
#contact-info {
    border-top: solid 1px #2f3337;
    width: 537px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Code in head for web font:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This displays perfectly in browser, but its not working in email. I know I cannot just paste the code in email, and that I need to preview it in browser, copy it directly from there, and paste it in email body, but its not displaying correctly. I am using Gmail.

Comment: What serverside language are you using?

Comment: For an HTML email, your best bet is to use `tables`, (think 90s web) And inline styling. CSS support in HTML emails is still some what lacking, for example, background images won't work in a lot of email clients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emails tend to strip header content, so you are unlikely to be able to add the external link for the new font.

As a rule, keep html in emails as simple as possible as their ability to render html is limited (especially Outlook). Remember that you will (probably) be sending it to a variety of email clients - they will all be slightly different.

This should help : https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 3):

Emails parses/renders very different as browsers do.
Outlook uses the render engine from WORD! look [here](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/wordhtml.htm)
You should add your css inline, should use tables instead of div etc.
Its a lot different to build websites! Gmail renders different as Outlook or Lotus will do.
I remeber, I added style="display:block" to all my images to remove a margin in gmail. look [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3132/how-to-stop-gmail-from-adding-a-margin-to-your-images/)

Testing, testing, testing :-)

Something like webfonts I would completly remove!

There are a lot of [templates](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html%20newsletters%20templates%20free) you can use.

Also some tools out there, which will put all your css inline.

Comment: Good point about Outlook's render engine. Working with Outlook is a nightmare.  When you know it is basically just Word, it does help bug-fix, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Float, Padding, Border-Top
```

CSS Tags are not alowed

and Tags Like `DIV` will not able to create design, in place of `div` use `Table` base structure in Email Content

See this link for help  [Guid To CSS Implementation in Email content](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: @chrisツ I had updated my answer, actually i want to tell that Div structure will not able to create design, use table structure

Comment: div was giving me problem, using table corrected the format in outlook

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Email Service Providers such as Yahoo and Google doesn't let your CSS code to kick in. if you want to use CSS in Email pages, you should change them into inline styles , that would do the trick, for example :

```
<div id="container" style="background-image:url(http://www.collegify.com/emailer/roads/delhi/images/Promotional-Flyer-for-Delhi-Front-1.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:600px; height:910px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 31px;">blah blah</div>
```